# when user signed in from Table 1 show only his data from Table 2

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables in my database. 
userTable (user_id, companyName, pass) which has all the users with their company name, and on login data comes from here. 
productionTable (production_id, companyName, deliveryNotes) also has got, company names with delivery notes.

in here the main idea is, whenever a user logedin with his companyName will see only his table.

I'd like to do something like below:

```
if (userInput === userInsideTable && companyInput === companyInsideTable) {show only his information}
```

here below is my login
so now should I apply the logic here in the login or another page

```
<?php
session_start();

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_db1');

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['myS'])) {
        $myU = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['myU']);
        $myP = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['myP']);
        $myC = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['myC']);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE myUsername = ? AND myPassword = ? AND myCompany = ?";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $myU, $myP, $myC);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['myU'] = $row['myUsername'];
            $_SESSION['myC'] = $row['myCompany'];
            session_write_close();
            echo ("<script>window.location = 'test.php';</script>");
        } else {
            echo ("<script>alert('Username/Password is Incorrect!')</script>");
            echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post">
            username<input type="text" name="myU" id="">
            pass <input type="password" name="myP" id="">
            company<input type="text" name="myC" id="">
            <input type="submit" value="login" name="myS">
        </form>
```

here is my test.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_db1');
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM productionTable WHERE company = " . $_SESSION['myC'] . " ");


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["production_id"];
        echo $row["company"];
        echo  $row["notes"];
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

what is the best approach to get only signed in user info... 
if user 1 with company x1 with pass 123 logged in he/she only sees related info from another table

can anyone propose a deferent logic perhaps  
for example  
a page with login and a page with result 
login page is user account management and result page production table or maybe not at all

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @CodeCreate nothing i mean no error and no data

Comment: do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string` when using `prepared statements` as it can subtly alter the values and offers no additional protection. User's passwords should be `hashed` using [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and validated using [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thanks. ill fix it . but its not my focus problem .. i just want to know what logic should i use to achieve my result

Comment: create the sql with a join on companyName perhaps?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius can you explain please

Comment: Instead of company name, you have to use user id for the relationship between production and user table.

Comment: in the `productionTable` is the column called `company` or `companyName` - or do both exist?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius would you please be kind enough to answer with example

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius can you propose a logic for whole process

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase im trying to figure out a proper logic as i mentioned in the bottom of my question

Comment: Please add your attempts to the question. Have you tried using a `JOIN` for this?

Comment: @NicoHaase i'm going to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question details certain columns in both tables yet the sql in `test.php` references a hitherto undeclared column - `company`. Assuming that the initial declaration of columns is correct and that both tables contain `companyName` details then it should be possible to forge a `join` between the tables using that common column.

None of the below is tested so forgive possible mistakes. There are issues you need to address regarding a user's password - it should be hash as per the comment made and that would affect the logic used in `index.php` to determine the session vars.

The sql in `test.php` attempts to create the union between the two tables and thus tie a user to a company.. it would be easier with proper sql schema and data! Note hte sql uses aliases for the table names to make the sql easier to read.

```
<?php
    
    #index.php
    
    session_start();
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( 
        $_POST['myS'],
        $_POST['myU'],
        $_POST['myP'],
        $_POST['myC']
    )) {
    
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_db1');
    
        $myU = $_POST['myU'];
        $myP = $_POST['myP'];
        $myC = $_POST['myC'];
        /*
        
            user password should be hashed!
            
        */
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) as `count` FROM `userTable` WHERE `myUsername` = ? AND `myPassword`=? and `myCompany` = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( "sss", $myU, $myP, $myC );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($count);
        
        if( $count==1 && $stmt->num_rows==1 ){
        
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['myU'] = $myU;
            $_SESSION['myC'] = $myC;
            session_write_close();
            
            exit(header('Location: test.php'));
        }
        
        
        echo "
        <script>
            alert('Username/Password is Incorrect!');
            location.search = 'error=true';
        </script>";
    }
    
?>
```

and the `test.php` file might be...

```
<?php
    
    #test.php
    
    session_start();
    if( isset(
        $_SESSION['myU'],
        $_SESSION['myC']
    ) ){
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_db1');
        
        $sql='select * from `userTable` u
                inner join `productionTable` p on p.companyName=u.companyName
                where p.companyName=? and u.myUsername=?';
        $stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_SESSION['myC'], $_SESSION['myU'] );
        $stmt->execute();
        $result=$stmt->get_result();
        
        while( $rs = $result->fetch_array( MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ){
            echo $rs[''];
        }
    }
```

Comment: note that the final piece of code `echo $rs[''];` is deliberately left as is - this is where you write out whatever data you wish.. it is just for illustration here...

Comment: many many thanks to you... allow me to try it out and apply your advise and I'll get back here and submit an answer that works for me .

Comment: btw this logical approach will it be good u think or better way out there ????

Comment: The best ways usually become clearer to you when you more fully understand the problem... alas for me the problem seems a little vague, I merely tried to provide code to suit what I believed your requirement to be ( before the changes/edits )

Comment: i'm most grateful .... if u have time can you plz send me a link that explained how to become a good php developer like yourself plz give me an honor with your advise

Comment: What does `if( $stmt->num_rows==1 )` do?

Comment: `num_rows` will always be 1 since you are always fetching one record. Did you mean to fetch `COUNT(*)` instead?